# Tag Schema select intersection

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have a, I think pretty common, schema:

samples <-> sample_labels <-> labels

Here's an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/61e723/3). I would like to achieve a selection of all samples that have all of the tags specified.

Given parameters of:

- `label.key=narf`, `label.value=zord`
- `label.key=foo`, `label.value=bar`

I only would like to retrieve samples that are having both of these labels. A where of

```
-- will find nothing cause conditions can't be satisfied
WHERE
  label.key = 'narf' AND label.value = 'zord'
  AND label.key = 'foo' AND label.value = 'bar'
```

will yield 0 rows (seems clear enough because no label tuple can actually fullfill these conditions. Given this:

```
-- will find either of "narf=zord", "foo=bar"
WHERE
  label.key = 'narf' AND label.value = 'zord'
  OR label.key = 'foo' AND label.value = 'bar'
```

Will yield all rows in the SQL Fiddle example because (again, seems clear enough to me) every label in that case will fulfill the conditions.

Even worse is this:

```
-- will also find "foo=zord" or "bar=narf" -> unwanted
WHERE
  (l.key IN ('foo', 'narf')) AND
  (l.value IN ('bar', 'zord'))
```

My brain is in meltdown mode and I'm pretty close to filtering thru the results in my code. It seems obvious that I'm simpy not smart enough to get the query correct.  :(

What is the query to get only samples that are correlated to ALL the given labels?

Comment: Try adding some brackets: WHERE
  (label.key = 'narf' AND label.value = 'zord')
  OR (label.key = 'foo' AND label.value = 'bar')

Comment: @George.Palacios Nope, sorry: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/37bb3/3 (neither the `AND`ed version)

Comment: I can't be understanding the problem them, could you post a sample of the results you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

You must ensure that both combinations exists.

> ```
> -- I'd like all samples that have labels of "narf=zord" AND "foo=bar"
> -- AND l.key = 'foo' AND l.value = 'bar'
> WITH pairs AS
> (
>     SELECT s.id AS sample_id, s.prefix AS sample, l.id AS label_id, l.key, l.value
>     FROM   samples s 
>     JOIN   sample_labels sl ON (s.id = sl.sample_id)
>     JOIN labels l ON (sl.label_id = l.id)
> )
> SELECT p.sample_id, p.sample, p.label_id, p.key, value
> FROM   pairs p
> WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
>                FROM   pairs 
>                WHERE sample_id = p.sample_id and key = 'narf' AND value = 'zord')
> AND    EXISTS (SELECT 1 
>                FROM   pairs 
>                WHERE sample_id = p.sample_id and key = 'foo' AND value = 'bar');
> ```
>
> ```
> sample_id | sample              | label_id | key  | value
> --------: | :------------------ | -------: | :--- | :----
>         1 | narf=zord & foo=bar |        1 | narf | zord 
>         1 | narf=zord & foo=bar |        2 | foo  | bar
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=876e940120685eb5493afb3a05928c7a)*

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using array aggregation in Postgres:

```
select s.*
from samples s 
  join sample_labels sl on sl.sample_id = s.id
  join labels l on l.id = sl.label_id
-- samples with at least those tags
where (l.key, l.value) in ( ('foo', 'bar'), ('narf', 'zord') )
group by s.id
-- only get those with exactly those tags
having array_agg(array[l.key, l.value] order by l.key, l.value) = array[ array['foo', 'bar'], array['narf', 'zord'] ]
```

Note that the `order by` is important in `array_agg` and the comparison value must also be ordered in that way, because `array[1,2]` is not the same as `array[2,1]`

Online example: http://rextester.com/BKQW78796

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need an autojoin on that one...
Let's try it this way:

```
SELECT s.id,
  s.prefix,
  l.id,
  l.key,
  l.value,
  l2.id,
  l2.key,
  l2.value
FROM
  samples s
  INNER JOIN sample_labels sl ON (s.id=sl.sample_id)
  INNER JOIN sample_labels sl2 ON (sl.sample_id = sl2.sample_id AND sl.label_id<>sl2.label_id)
  INNER JOIN labels l ON (sl.label_id = l.id)
  INNER JOIN labels l2 ON (sl2.label_id = l2.id)
WHERE
  l.key = 'narf' 
  AND l.value = 'zord'
  AND l2.key = 'foo'
  AND l2.value = 'bar'
;
```

I get only sample 1 as a result. Was it what you wanted ?